# white reloading checkbox to be checked defualt angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-forms

I need a default checkbox on for users one while loading this page ie I need to search for users as default while submitting for and also users checkbox must be checked  initially while loading
I am sorry I am new to angular searched a lot for this thing please help

```html
<form (submit)="abc(postform)" #postform="ngForm">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your search" name="searchparam" ngModel  #searchparam="ngModel"  required  >
        <input type="checkbox" name="users" [checked]=true ngModel #users="ngModel"  id="users" [checked]="user"  onclick="if(users.checked) {pets.checked=false}"  required />users
        <input type="checkbox" name="pets" id="pets" ngModel #pets="ngModel" onclick="if(pets.checked) {pets.checked=false}" />pets
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have `[checked]` bound to two different values, that will not work. A better solution is to set `[checked]` to `"user"` as you have done the second time, and then set `user` to `true`. So your code would change to

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="users" ngModel #users="ngModel"  id="users" [checked]="user"  onclick="if(users.checked) {pets.checked=false}"  required />
```

and then is ts, set `user` to be true when you define it

```
user = true
```